# Convert tree to a list node with root to leaf paths .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I have a n-ary tree structure that has nodes with children. Each node is a "folder" and folders can have child folders (i.e. nested folder) or simply a file (leaf node).  I want to convert this structure to a list of folders where each folder name is a composite root to last folder and contains the all the leaf nodes in that last folder.  So, for example:

- Root

  - Folder1

    - File1
    - File2
  - Folder2

    - Folder3

      - File3
    - File 4

Would result in a List with Folder/File members

1. Folder1 - File1, File2
2. Folder2.Folder3 - File3
3. Folder2 - File4

Sample code/setup:

```
    public interface INode
    {
    }
    
    public class Folder : INode
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<INode>? Children { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class File : INode
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    
    var tree = new Folder() { Name = "Root" };
    var folder1 = new Folder() { Name = "Folder1" };
    var file1 = new TreeConverter.File() { Name = "File1" };
    var file2 = new TreeConverter.File() { Name = "File2" };
    folder1.Children = new List<INode> { file1, file2 };
    var folder2 = new Folder() { Name = "Folder2" };
    var folder3 = new Folder() { Name = "Folder3" };
    var file3 = new TreeConverter.File() { Name = "File3" };
    var file4 = new TreeConverter.File() { Name = "File4" };
    folder3.Children = new List<INode> { file3 };
    folder2.Children = new List<INode>() { folder3, file4 };
    tree.Children = new List<INode>() { folder1, folder2 };
    
    List<Folder> folders = ConvertTreeToListofFoldersWithEachEntryNamedRootToLastFolderWithAllContainingFileNodes(tree);
    // folders would contain folders named as such: [Folder1, Folder2.Folder3, Folder2]
    // which one could iterate over the children of each node to get the leaf nodes.
```

Thank you.

Ps: This is a variation of [Printing all the paths in a tree from root to each leaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72239497/printing-all-the-paths-in-a-tree-from-root-to-each-leaf) I think. Just the output is not a print but another data structure.

Update: I found the solution, although I changed/simplified the tree node structure.

```
    public enum NodeType
    {
        Folder,
        File
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Node> Children { get; set;}
        public NodeType Type { get; set; }
    
        public Node(string name, NodeType type)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Type = type;
            this.Children = new List<Node>();
        }
    }
    
    // Tree Setup
    var tree = new Node("Root", NodeType.Folder);
    var folder1 = new Node("Folder1", NodeType.Folder );
    var file1 = new Node ("File1", NodeType.File );
    var file2 = new Node ("File2", NodeType.File );
    var file3 = new Node ("File3", NodeType.File );
    var file4 = new Node ("File4", NodeType.File );
    var folder2 = new Node ("Folder2", NodeType.Folder );
    var folder3 = new Node ("Folder3", NodeType.Folder );
    
    folder1.Children = new List<Node> { file1, file2 };
    folder3.Children = new List<Node> { file3 };
    folder2.Children = new List<Node>() { folder3, file4 };
    tree.Children = new List<Node>() { folder1, folder2 };
    
    
    // Action
    var foldersWithFiles = GetFoldersWithFiles(tree);
    
    foreach(var folder in foldersWithFiles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Folder: {folder.Key}");
        Console.WriteLine($" Files: {string.Join(",", folder.Value)}");
    }
    
     Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetFoldersWithFiles(Node root)
    {
        var foldersWithFiles = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        Traverse(root, root.Name, foldersWithFiles);
        return foldersWithFiles;
    }
    
    
    void Traverse(Node node, string path, Dictionary<string, List<string>> foldersWithFiles)
    {
        var childernFiles = node.Children.Where(child => child.Type == NodeType.File);
        if (childernFiles.Any())
        {
            foldersWithFiles[path] = childernFiles.Select(child => child.Name).ToList();
        }
    
        foreach (var child in node.Children)
        {
            Traverse(child, $"{path}/{child.Name}", foldersWithFiles);
        }
    }
```

The output being

```
Folder: Root/Folder1
 Files: File1,File2
Folder: Root/Folder2
 Files: File4
Folder: Root/Folder2/Folder3
 Files: File3
```

Comment: The list in that answer is one list node that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with this method in the `Folder` class:

```
    public List<Folder> Flattened() {
        // The result that will be returned:
        List<Folder> flat = new();
        if (Children is not null) {
            // The container for files that might be in this folder:
            Folder current = new() { Name = Name, Children = new() };
            foreach (INode child in Children) {
                if (child is Folder) {
                    // Get flattened folder from recursive call
                    List<Folder> flatChildren = ((Folder) child).Flattened();
                    // Mutate the received folders to include the current folder name
                    foreach (Folder flatChild in flatChildren) {
                        flatChild.Name = Name + "." + flatChild.Name;
                    }
                    flat.AddRange(flatChildren);
                } else {
                    current.Children.Add(child);
                }
            }
            // If this folder has any files, then also add a copy  
            //      of the current folder in the result, but only with its files
            if (current.Children.Count > 0)  {
                flat.Add(current);
            }
        }
        return flat;
    }
```

In your main code, call it like this:

```
List<Folder> flat = tree.Flattened();
```